# Webpack HMR module.accept variable instead of string

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-hmr

Trying to run as such:

```
var path = './App';
module.hot.accept(path, () => {
    renderComonent();
})
```

does not work!

Only:

```
module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
        renderComonent();
    })
```

In the first scenario it will refresh the page, while in the second it will not. 
PS: I'm using a new fresh `create-react-app` sample.

In my opinion this is a bug from HMR/webpack.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the way the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` plugin works is by parsing the arguments given to `module.hot.accept` at compile time.

The parser is not clever enough to follow variable references in the AST, hence your example does not work.

You can see how the plugin is implemented here (in particular the parser "hook" which finds calls to `module.hot.accept()`): https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js#L116

So this is expected behaviour, not a bug. (Even if confusing.)

Comment: from what are you describing is more of a limitation. Otherwise I can't see why not supporting dynamic paths

Comment: Take it up on the webpack GitHub repo as an issue. I'm just answering why your code didn't work. ;-)